# How to split a data frame column according to character position in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

how do i split a dataframe column according to character position in Python ? 
Example of dataframe column:

```
YDW10CMPMRPA                        
8N940CMPMRPA                        
J5F10DTS22ND                         
YJD30NEWTRPA                        
8M9A1DTS3NRV
```

Split out into 3 column, 
first column only contain first 5 character

```
YDW10                        
8N940                        
J5F10                        
YJD30                        
8M9A1
```

2nd column contain 6th to 9th character

```
CMPM                        
CMPM                        
DTS2                        
NEWT                        
DTS3
```

3rd column contain 10th to 12th character

```
RPA                               
RPA                          
2ND                        
RPA                        
NRV
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try taking substrings here:

```
df['first']  = df['column'].str[:5]
df['second'] = df['column'].str[5:9]
df['third']  = df['column'].str[9:12]
```